# _firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler is not getting called when my iOS app is in terminated state

Tags: ios, flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am using flutter_callkit_incoming to show call notification in my application. I am using firebase messaging to receive the notification. It works fine when app is in foreground or when it's just gone in the background but when the app is cleared from apps or it is in detached mode it's not working.

When I receive above notification in my flutter application, I invoke below function from https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_callkit_incoming

```
`  FlutterCallkitIncoming.showCallkitIncoming(callKitParams);`
```

I am using callkit params as per documentation, it works when app is in foreground. The only issue it doesn't work when app is in detached state, in iOS.

Answer (score 0):

With IOS, please test all case:
[image]

- Foreground: work
- Background: add @pragma('vm:entry-point') to your _firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler() function.
- Terminate (kill app): with case terminate, you must run app in release mode, because ios in debug mode will disconnect when you kill app.
  https://docs.flutter.dev/testing/build-modes#release

Comment: I tried this but got no success. In the terminated state, _firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler() is not called and no print statements were printed.

Comment: You can't print or debug when you run app in release mode (on IOS). It only working in debug mode. Please show me your code file.

Comment: This is example when you use FCM to wake up incoming callkit. https://github.com/hiennguyen92/flutter_callkit_incoming/blob/master/example/lib/main.dart

Comment: Hi @Quang Duong, please share me your email address so that we can connect.